# MassTransit duplicate message detection

Tags: c#, .net, queue, masstransit

I want to enable Duplicate Message detection feature on Azure topic/queue

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection)

I can use custom *MessageId* like  `12345.2017/payment` i.e. it can be any string and I take responsibility of uniqueness of it.

I try to pass my custom *MessageId* when I send/publish message

```
await bus.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(message, x =>
{
    x.MessageId = someGuid;//only GUID here, strings not allowed
});
```

But thing is that  I can pass Guid only, how to pass a string value, is there any workaround, please ?

Is there another way how to deal with duplicate message detection with MassTransit ?

Comment: Have the same use-case, would be great if this is possible with MassTransit

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit always uses GUIDs for its message ids, so using a string message id isn't supported by that abstraction.

However, you can convert a string to a GUID by using a MD5 or SHA1 GUID instead of a random GUID. I discuss [GUID details](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/11/few-words-on-guids.html) on my blog. I also have a [GUID library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Guids) that can create MD5 or SHA1 GUIDs for you.

As a final note, do be aware that any duplicate detection on the message bus side can only detect duplicate *publishing*; it cannot prevent duplicate *receives*. If you need to prevent duplicate receives of a persistent message, the  you'll need to do duplicate detection yourself from within the consumer (using, e.g., CosmosDb).